# Is there a way to see granular per-visit data in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I've started using Google Analytics very recently and I'm a bit lost with the sea of options (have been using Sitemeter before for some time). I've clicked through the service a lot but couldn't find what I'm accustomed to.

I can see multitude of **aggregated** statistics in GA like:

- charts of browser share
- lists of country share
- lists of most visited URLs within the page

and so on, but I would actually like to analyze **each of the visits themselves**.

Something like:

> 1. User X, France, Chrome, 7 pageviews between 18:01 and 18:15, entered on a.htm and exited on b.htm
> 2. User Y, UK, Firefox, 1 pageview at 18:20, entered on c.htm

Is there an easy way to see the reports in this way (perhaps by clicking a link to a separate page to see that particular session's stats)? How to navigate there if so?

Comment: Yes you can see visits and combine some data while viewing traffic. But to get a report that contains everything you listed above would require a custom built report.

Comment: I didn't have much time to play with GA, so finally I've installed also StatCounter in which doing things I've written is much easier. Anyway thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

It is very difficult to get individual user session data out of Google Analytics. The closest you could get is to set up a series of Advanced Segments to try and drill down to individual users (something like hostname + country + landing page might work).

If you have access to the server logs you might be able to get this with a log parser - or build some custom queries based on that data.

You may also want check out analytics packages that are more focused on UX analysis or marketing automation. These usually have an individual session tracking component, but are rarely free.