# How can I view page-views of specific URL's with question mark (?) tags using Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a specific issue regarding Google Analytics and its tracking of direct traffic that I'm hoping someone here will be able to help me with. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you :) The closest I found as an answer to my question is [Granular per Visit Data?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38406/is-there-a-way-to-see-granular-per-visit-data-in-google-analytics) but this is not an answer to my question specifically.

The short version of the question, if you want to take a stab at it, is this from below: "When I check for traffic in GA after using these links to test them, I get hits to xyz.com/a but it's hard to find hits to xyz.com/a?2" Where in GA should I go to see this detail? I'll explain it more below.

Using Google Analytics I want to track direct traffic with a short link that I create myself... I get the sense that Analytics isn't set up for the specificity that I'm looking for in tracking (it is set up for tagging URL's using the GA system, but I don't want those long URLs that tagging creates), but can do this none the less.

I'll give a fictional example below for illustrative purposes and perhaps you can help me understand how to get what I'm looking for.

I have xyz.com/a which is my landing page. I have a thousand clients which I'm sending this link to in the physical mail via QR code. Each person gets a unique QR Code. The unique codes are, for the first client xyz.com/a?1 - for the second - xyz.com/a?2 and so on for all one thousand clients.

When I check for traffic in GA after using these links to test them, I get hits to xyz.com/a but it's hard to find hits to xyz.com/a?2 , for example. But, I know that somewhere along the lines Google is tracking this. How can I drill down to find a list of all the links such as xyz.com/a?1 and xyz.com/a?2 that people have visited? It seems like GA takes all of the xyz.com/a?X type links and aggregates their statistics to one xyz.com/a link.

I know that Google is capturing this at some point because I have found xyz.com/a2 listed in GA under Real-Time -> Overview when I'm viewing that real time page and I go to the particular link. However, I want to find out which of these unique links are visited without having to sit and watch the Real-Time feed 24/7. All help is appreciated, perhaps there is something I'm missing. The reason I'm not using the built-in tagging feature with GA is because that will make the URL much longer and I desire a shorter URL with no URL shortener being used.

If what I'm looking for is not possible through GA, the site is built on Orchard CMS: is there a way to see these statistics through Orchard CMS somehow? Thanks again.

Comment: If you can find a way to shorten up the narrative here, as clearly as possible, you might receive more responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question, and found a site that helped me. The link to this site is posted below, I hope it answers your questions:

[Making URLs Better Through Content Grouping in Google Analytics](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2014/02/27/urls-content-grouping-google-analytics/#sr=g&m=o&cp=or&ct=-tmc&st=(opu%20qspwjefe)&ts=1405131169)

The author does an excellent job at presenting this topic.

Comment: It's best to summarize the content found in links so that if they're no longer available, the answer will still remain helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for, the stuff after the question mark, in Google Analytics.

It's here: Behavior > Site Content > All Pages or any of the other items under Site Content.